# Class has no attribute, even though set

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

I've been making a dungeons and dragons themed game in python and have been using classes for the player and maps.

But when trying to fetch an array from the map class,it tells me there is no attribute named by this, but it has definitely been set.

Heres the map class

```
class Map_1:

    def __init__ (self):
        self.Title = "Default"
        self.Spawn = [4, 2]
        self.map = [...]
```

I then go on to try and use this

```
Map = Map_1
current_pos = Map.Spawn
```

Now usually this would be embedded in another Class, but i tried seeing if it was classes clashing by taking it out and running it without a class and i still get an error.
This is my error

```
class Map_1 has no attribute 'Spawn'
```

Comment: You are setting the instance  attribute, not the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Martijn's answer, you are missing the '()' after 'Map_1'.
When you say

```
Map = Map_1
```

that needs to be:

```
Map = Map_1()
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is easier to understand if you don't quite understand the terminology

Answer (score 3):

Your *class* has no such attribute no. Only *instances* of the class would have that attribute, but you never create one.

Create an instance by *calling* the class:

```
Map = Map_1()  # call the class
current_pos = Map.Spawn
```

Comment: Damnit, thank you, i look like such a rookie. But at least it's a reminder to closely examine the syntax, thanks again.